# Error message when starting ddev laravel: "Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: web container failed" (zfs)

Tags: laravel, docker, ddev, zfs

When I initially cloned a company repository and tried to start via `ddev start` I got the error message `Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: web container failed`.
The container ddev-website-web stays unhealthy. The browser page shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: The error is a known problem with overlayFS on ZFS, see [Moby #45890 on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/45890)

**Long answer**:
You can check easily, if the error fits to you.

When the ddev-web container is started you can login into the container via `ddev ssh` then show the user and groups of the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

If the user and group is root, there will be an `apache`-Folder inside and in this folder the correct files will be inside.
If you try to remove the folder with `sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled` you will get an error `invalid argument`.

This pointed my college to this issue: [issue 46640 on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/46640)

So please check, if you're using overlay mount with zfs with `docker info`

```
Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: zfs
```

Then you can use this **Solution**:

To avoid this error, just do like in [docker docu-use zfs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/) described.

- *Be sure to backup all containers that You can't get via docker pull!*
- stop docker `service docker stop`
- make sure to have enough free space (temporary)
- create backup of docker-files: `sudo cp -au /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bk`
- if necessary, unmount mounted docker folders

  - `cat /proc/mounts | grep docker`
  - `sudo umount /path` (source: [Github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6077#issuecomment-613817415))
- edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add

  - `{ "storage-driver": "zfs" }`
- after saving file, start docker again `service docker start`
- after a short time `docker info` should show `Storage Driver: zfs`
- if everything works, remove the former docker folder `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker.bk`

Your problem should be solved.